# How to remove Selection formular from crystalView after successful filtered record in other to view all records

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, selectionchanging

i have two crystal Reports with different tables (PatientBiodataReport.rpt and StaffBiodataReport.rpt) and I have one search box (textbox) to filter the two reports and return the result to CrystalReportViewer1 and a button to return all record (View All)... So after successfully search for patient in PatientBiodataReport.rpt, If I decided to change control to return all Records in StaffBiodataReport.rpt,but an error will prompt indicate that the previous selection formula from PatientBiodata is still be using will have change the CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource to StaffBiodataReport.
**Please how can i remove selection formula of the previous crystal report**

**>>These are the codes for search button<<**

```
 Private Sub searchbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles searchbtn.Click
    If Biodatasearchtxt.Text <> "" Then
        If GroupBox1.Text = "Patient Biodata Reports Controls" Then
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Application.StartupPath + "\Reports\PatientBiodataReport.rpt"
            CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{patient_biodata.healthcare_no}='" & Biodatasearchtxt.Text.ToString() & "'"
        Else
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Application.StartupPath + "\Reports\StaffBiodataReport.rpt"
            CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{staff_biodata.employee_id}='" & Biodatasearchtxt.Text.ToString() & "'"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Please Enter the Search criteria", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If

End Sub
```

**>>These are the codes for View All button<<**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    With CrystalReportViewer1
        If GroupBox1.Text = "Patient Biodata Reports Controls" Then
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Application.StartupPath + "\Reports\PatientBiodataReport.rpt"
        Else
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Application.StartupPath + "\Reports\StaffBiodataReport.rpt"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[This is the screen shot of the report and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEu62.jpg)

[Screenshot of execution of the selection formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWIjk.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the first block of code you may want to use :

```
Me.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
Me.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

After each attempt to change the **SelectionFormula**

Comment: @Olasquare, Works for me. Though I manipulate the Crystal Report totally by code. How do you populate your Crystal Report  with data from Database Table ? Also, please specify the Database type and VS version and .net framework used.

Comment: I created crystal report, and attached table from database and design how it will display.. Then send select which crystal report will show on crystalReportViewer at appropriate time...  Using sql database (SQL server Management ostudio 2012).. Usingvisual studio 2013 and . NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: @Olasquare,
CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{staff_biodata.employee_id}='" & Biodatasearchtxt.Text.ToString() & "'"
 .... What is the DataType of this record [staff_biodata.employee_id] ?
If it is of a type [BigInt] as I assume that this record is a Primary Key, then your Sql Statement is incorrect. Is it ?

Comment: The datatype for employee_id is nvarchar and it is primary key.. @evry1falls that sql statement is working perfectly but selection formula always hold the last query of one crystal report while have changed crystalReportViewer1.reportsource from patientbiodata to staffbiodata... So I want a code to always release the selection formula or selection formula that will select all record in the staffbiodata.

Comment: ok @Olasquare, Do you get a valid result when you run this selection alone ?
CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{staff_biodata.employee_id}='" & Biodatasearchtxt.Text.ToString() & "'"
Could you please send me a screenshot, using it alone without the other one !!

Comment: yes i get expected result while run that statement.. i don't know how to add image to this comment